# PHP Max execution time error even though I'm running from CLI

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I'm trying to reindex my catalog_url_rewrite table (Magento website) through the command line using the command "php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url" in /shell. I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /var/www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php on line 141
```

The file and line on the error varies.

I've double checked to confirm that php in the command line is indeed using the php-cli version (by using "php -i") and that there are no limits in its config that should yield such an error.

I've also looked around to see if any magento file is setting the "set_time_limit" manually, but couldn't find anything that points that way. I can't find the 60 seconds max_execution_time anywhere.

Any idea on what's going on?

Edit:

So far I've tried:

- Running "php -d max_execution_time=0 indexer.php --reindex catalog_url"
- Setting "set_time_limit(9000);" on indexer.php directly.
- Running "php -i" to see "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli" & "Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini"
- Setting max_execution_time on fpm's php.ini to 61 just to see if it was using it by accident.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that the cli version of the PHP is using a different php.ini as opposed to the web server version of PHP.

You can remove the script execution time limit by adding this line (after `<?php` of `indexer.php`)

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Src: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: while you are at it, set increase the memory limit to the `indexer.php` (as magento is quite resource hungry) like so: `ini_set('memory_limit','64M');` (increase the value to fit your need)

Comment: I already had "set_time_limit(9000);" there, but it appears to ignore it. Regarding the memory limit, it's set to 512M so I don't think thats the problem, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web server installation (Apache2 PHP, FPM ...), but you'll probably find a different php.ini for the CLI execution. Just set the time limit in the cli/php.ini configuration file and reload the web server configuration.

Comment: It is php-fpm, and I've checked the phpinfo in the command line to make sure it's using the config it should, and it appears to be so: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: Have you tried to specify the max execution time when calling PHP through CLI with the -d option ?
php -d max_execution_time=0 script.php

Comment: No, I'm running another test right now, but I'll try that right after.

Comment: Ok I've ran it like that, still the same error though: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded